# Javascript Entering Test For Null in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, testing, null

I'm currently trying to fill some fields in my forms. I'm doing a test where if `extnReason` and `extnDt` are `null`, I do nothing. But for some reason, it keeps entering the check and loading my fields with `null`, which I don't want.

```
function preloadFields() {

//these values are coming in as null
var extnReason = '<%=extnReason%>';
var extnDt = '<%=extnDt%>';

//set Extension Date blank on load
$('#extnDt').val("");

alert("reason ++++ " + extnReason);
alert("extnDt ++++ " + extnDt);

//it is entering these tests but I don't want them to
if(extnReason != null || extnReason != "null"){ 
    console.log("entered reason");
    $('#extnReason').val(extnReason);
}

if(extnDt != null || extnDt != "null") {
    console.log("entered extnDt");
    $('#extnDt').val(extnDt);
}

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need

```
if(extnReason != null && extnReason != "null")
```

instead of

```
if(extnReason != null || extnReason != "null")
```

Because if `extnReason` is `'null'` the first condition `'null' != null` would return `true`, so an OR check would evaluate to `true` and therefore enter the block of code which sets your value.

Same for the other if condition...

Alternative way of preloading your fields: you could also just set the `value` attribute of your input tag instead of using `preloadFields`? i.e. something like:

```
 <input type="text" id="extnDt" value="${extnDt != null ? extnDt : ''}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! For some reason, I thought the `||` would state that either would have to be true to enter the operation, and that `&&` meant that both would have to become true to enter the operation. My code doesn't allow for your alternative way of doing it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, just to clarify:  `&&` is AND: both conditions have to be true, `||` is OR, only one condition has to be true.

Comment: I see. Why is it that in this case it's both `null` and `"null"`? This strikes me as odd because it's showing that both exists as true. I was led to believe that `null` meant no value at all and `"null"` is a `String`.

Comment: That's right, when you are using `||` you are asking whether your string is NOT `null` (no value) OR whether it is NOT `'null'` (i.e. the string).  As the string `'null'` is NOT no value, the first part of your if condition is `true` and therefore the whole if is true and your branch is entered.  Does that make sense?